# EXCEL VBA: getting the integer value of mm in today's date

Tags: excel, vba

novice programmer here and it's my first question here.

I'm interested in doing some invoicing using excel, and a part of that is generating invoice numbers, e.g. 1870001-1879999, referring to the year 2018, the month of July, and the 1st to 9999th invoice of this month.

To do this, I've written a bit of code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim MValue As String
Dim XValue As Integer

MValue = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")
LValue = Left(MValue, 2)
XValue = CInt(LValue)
Range("K1").Value = XValue

End Sub
```

This would give me "7" as an integer in the cell K1, which I can then multiply by 10000 and add to 1800000 to give the baseline value of 1870000.

I have two questions:

1) what's a better way to do this problem? My method seems incredibly long. (dates are stored awkwardly in excel)

2) why is it that:
    Range("K1").Value = XValue * 10000
   causes an error?

Thanks.

Comment: Use Long rather than Integer btw and so  Dim XValue As Long and CLng(LValue). Your error is an overflow one.

Comment: Rethink your invoice identifier before continuing. The date should be stored as 07 not 7 or Oct-Dec will be confused with Jan and you will have to determine the length of the invoice number (7 0r 8) in order to retrieve a certain month's invoices with wildcards.

Comment: As a general rule, identifiers should be `String` rather than a number. And then build the string up (`Year2Char` & `Month2Char` & `Number4Char`). This negates the need for any intricate maths and possible ordering issues when numbers strip/add leading zeros.

Comment: @Jeeped thanks so much! come October, I would've been crushed.

Comment: @AJD I see your way creates a bulletproof way of generating the identifier, but how would I go about +1 to the invoice number each time if it's saved as a string? would the code first have to convert the string into a long integer first, then convert back to a string?

Comment: @KsL. You could convert the last four characters of your previous invoice into an Integer/Long, add 1 and then convert back to string, as you have suggested. Other options exist depending on how you are storing your invoice numbers (e.g. if your sequence number is a separate field from your date, then you could increment that number and convert to string) - but your suggestion is the simplest. I am assuming that when a new month rolls over, you will reset to "0001".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because Integer cannot handle the size of the number you are trying to pass. You will get an overflow error.

Declare as Long to avoid this.

```
Dim XValue As Long 
CLng(LValue)
```

What you have written could be re-written as:

```
Range("K1").Value = Month(Date) * 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Day` and `Month` functions. Here's one of the possible solutions:

```
Sub G()
    Dim dt As Date, d, m, s
    dt = Now
    d = Day(dt): m = Month(dt)
    s = d & m & GenerateID()
End Sub
Function GenerateID()
    GenerateID = "SOMETHING"
End Function
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand the GenerateID="SOMETHING" part, how do I get this to actually be sequential invoice numbers?

Comment: You could store this number somewhere in the book or in invisible name.